# ElasticSearch 5.x Context Suggester - single context multiple value

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to use completion context with multiple value.
Context accept only one value.

```
string contextValue = "10";
List<string> listOfContextValues = new List<string> {"10", "20","30"};
var a = Client.Search<Post>(s => s
            .Suggest(su => su
                .Completion("categories", cs => cs
                    .Field(f => f.CSuggest)
                    .Prefix(query)
                    .Contexts(co => co
                        .Context("sourceid",
                            cd => cd.Context(contextValue)
                    )
                )
            )
        ));
```

I don't know how to filter my suggest field with listOfContextValues.

**Update**

When i using a for loop and passing single context as filter and storing result in a list.

And also using Russ suggested code and storing result in a list.
But Some result are missing in second list.

As you can see in below:

```
var socialNetworks = srvUser.GetUserSocialNetworks(userId);

List<string> tags = new List<string>();
foreach (var socialNetwork in socialNetworks)
{
    var result = Client.Search<Post>(s => s
        .Suggest(su => su
            .Completion("categories", cs => cs
                .Field(f => f.CSuggest)
                .Prefix(query)
                .Contexts(co => co
                    .Context("sourceid",
                        cd => cd.Context(socialNetwork)
                    )
                )
            )
        ));
    List<string> br = result.Suggest["categories"].SelectMany(x => x.Options)
        .Select(y => y.Text).Distinct().ToList();
    tags.AddRange(br);
}

var searchResponse = Client.Search<Post>(s => s
    .Suggest(su => su
        .Completion("categories", cs => cs
            .Field(f => f.CSuggest)
            .Prefix(query)
            .Contexts(co => co
                .Context("sourceid", socialNetworks
                    .Select<string, Func<SuggestContextQueryDescriptor<Post>, ISuggestContextQuery>>(v => cd => cd.Context(v))
                    .ToArray()

                )
            )
        )
    )
);
List<string> sa = searchResponse.Suggest["categories"].SelectMany(x => x.Options).Select(y => y.Text).Distinct().ToList();
if (sa.Count != tags.Count)
{
    // >>>>> counts are not the same
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.Context(...)` takes a `params Func<SuggestContextQueryDescriptor<T>, ISuggestContextQuery>[]` as the second argument](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/5.x/src/Nest/Search/Suggesters/ContextSuggester/SuggestContextQuery.cs#L74-L75), so for a collection of context values you can do

```
void Main()
{
    var client = new ElasticClient();
    var listOfContextValues = new List<string> { "10", "20", "30" }; 
    var query = "query";

    var searchResponse = client.Search<Post>(s => s
                .Suggest(su => su
                    .Completion("categories", cs => cs
                        .Field(f => f.CSuggest)
                        .Prefix(query)
                        .Contexts(co => co
                            .Context("sourceid",
                                listOfContextValues
                                    .Select<string, Func<SuggestContextQueryDescriptor<Post>, ISuggestContextQuery>>(v => cd => cd.Context(v))
                                    .ToArray()
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
}

public class Post
{
    public CompletionField CSuggest { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks .it works. but when putting search in a for loop and passing single context value to context and merging responds, it returns more result than your code.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Perhaps you can edit your question to provide more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for size ?

```
  ...s =>
         s.Completion("categories",
            cs=> cs.
               Field(p => p.Suggestion)
                    .Contexts(
                        ctx =>
                            ctx.Context("sid", d => d.Context(value))
                    .Prefix(searchText)
                    .Size(10);
```

Comment: No. i am looking for a way to filter suggest field with multiple values (like list).

Comment: then my anwser is not the correct one. you should check @russcam's answer